# Do Wallets need to be verified or activated? Crypto Support asking me to do that

Tags: blockchain, wallet, fraud, verification

1.5Bitcoins were stolen form me in 2019, and a company Merawing contacted me a few weeks again, saying that they work with Crypto Regulation of Cyprus and that they would help me getting my bitcoins back. Every step we did is double checked and confirmed by Crypto Support in Cyprus.
After having invested already 25'000 Euro to verify some steps in the process, when I wanted to send the btc to my Exchanger, an error occured and the btc were sent to another Wallet (not mine). They said I was so lucky that that wallet doesn't belong to anyone and that so they could save it under my name. Being a new wallet needs now to be activated and verified and this requires an additional turnover of 40'000 Euro.

Is it true and correct that a wallet needs to be activated and verified by specific turnovers before the btc can be send to a personal Wallet in the Exchanger or is this just a clever scam?

Many thanks.

Comment: Hi Startraveller, this sounds very much like you're being scammed. I've linked two topics that go into more detail on similar situations.

Comment: Merawing.net domain was only registered a few months ago. most of the website content is copied from bitcoin.org. Merawing's contact page gives a UK phone number but a Cyprus address. I'd guess Merawing and the Crypto Regulation of Cyprus are fake entities run by the same criminals.

Comment: Definitely a scam